# How do I use the TripleDESCryptographyServiceProvider class?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, filestream, tripledes

I'm fiddling around with cryptography in c#. My file is getting encrypted, but decrypting is not possible. I get a CryptographyException "Bad Data". I think it has something to do with the encoding, but I nowhere use any encoding or bytes.

```
// Encrypts the data
    public bool encrypt ( ) {
        try {
            // Create or open the specified file.
            FileStream fStream = File.Open ( _encPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate );

            // Create a CryptoStream using the FileStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream ( fStream,
                _tdes.CreateEncryptor ( _tdes.Key, _tdes.IV ),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write );

            // Create a StreamWriter using the CryptoStream.
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter ( cStream );

            // Write the data to the stream 
            // to encrypt it.
            sWriter.WriteLine ( _content );

            // Close the streams and
            // close the file.
            sWriter.Close ( );
            cStream.Close ( );
            fStream.Close ( );
        } catch ( CryptographicException e ) {
            Console.WriteLine ( "A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message );
            return false;
        } catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException e ) {
            Console.WriteLine ( "A file access error occurred: {0}", e.Message );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

 // Decrypts the file
    public bool decrypt ( ) {
        try {
            // Create or open the specified file. 
            FileStream fStream = File.Open ( _path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate );

            // Create a CryptoStream using the FileStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream ( fStream,
                _tdes.CreateDecryptor ( _tdes.Key, _tdes.IV ),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read ); // Exception happens here

            // Create a StreamReader using the CryptoStream.
            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader ( cStream );

            // Read the data from the stream 
            // to decrypt it.
            String val = sReader.ReadLine ( );

            // Close the streams and
            // close the file.
            sReader.Close ( );
            cStream.Close ( );
            fStream.Close ( );

            File.WriteAllText ( _decPath, val );
        } catch ( CryptographicException e ) {
            Console.WriteLine ( "A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message );
            return false;
        } catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException e ) {
            Console.WriteLine ( "A file access error occurred: {0}", e.Message );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Anybody got some ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question. My method is totally different as is the method of encryption.

EDIT 2: [image: Hex dump]

Comment: Ciphertexts can contain bytes of any value. It doesn't have to correspond to any *valid* encoding, which leads to dropped bytes. Don't use StreamWriter or StreamReader if you're handling binary data.

Comment: What is the plain text and iv that is being encrypted and the key? Input and output that can be copy/pasted from the question to a test environment helps.

Comment: It is a better practice to pass arguments rather than using instance variables, this especially helps debugging/testing.

Comment: The iv needs to be the same for decryption as encryption, this is generally accomplished by prepending the iv to the encrypted data.

Comment: IV is the same. I create the Cryptographer() class once, which in turn creates _tdes once. Key and IV gets generated once and encryption/decryption uses the same _tdes.

Comment: Here is the thing: You state that everything is correct but then that it is not working. There is little doubt that the .net code works and your code looks correct. That leaves us without being able to see the data and unable to help further without that (sample data). We need the data just prior to and immediately after the decryption method, in hex and copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working for me in linqpad 5 (.net 4.6).

Are you making sure to either delete or properly clear the files between runs?  Considering the way you are using streams to write to the encrypted files, you are probably only partially updating the file as a whole from run to run.

Comment: This is just a test build. Not closing the program between encrypting and decrypting. Still have to find a way to store keys, so I just keep the app running for now to be able to use the same key.

Comment: The example code in the question doesn't show you clearing the file.  If you are re-using it in your program, what can happen is that when the encrypted contents become shorter, it might leave behind some of the old bits.  Example, if your encrypted contents are 12345, then you update the file with new encrypted contents ABC, you'll be left with ABC45

Comment: I get what you mean, but that shouldn't be a problem. I have a text file which contains "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet". I encrypted this once, it currently sits in the 'encrypted' folder. When I run a decrypt command on that file I immediately get the exception. The file hasn't been used again by encrypt and hasn't been written into again.

Comment: Here's what I've been using to test (works for me unless I go from large encrypted content to small encrypted content).  https://gist.github.com/kennethito/7c6fa579a2087810b8e7

Comment: Another (albeit not exactly identical) example of it working.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mh0LsS

Comment: I'm going crazy. Created a new solution in Visual Studio. Copy pasted your code. Added a static main method and it runs like a charm.

Comment: Encoding issues pop up once in a while. As Artjom stated, sometimes this leads e.g. to dropped or altered bytes (e.g. line endings, null/EOF characters etc.)